# Git - Get Current Working Copy Version

Tags: git, github

I am editing a project with git on multiple computers. How do I check the current version I am running on a computer?

For example, each time I commit, I use a version number and include it in the commit message. Is there a way for me to retrieve the current commit message for the working copy I am using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git does not have a concept of a "Revision Number". It has a commit hash. You won't know your commit hash until you've actually commited, so you cannot get the "current hash".

If you want the commit hash of the previous commit, use `git log -1`. If you need the output to be *just* the hash, then xpapad's answer is what you are looking for.

If you mean the actual version of Git (your question was a little ambiguous to me), then use `git version`.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, let me try again... each time I commit in Git, I add a version number as the commit message. Then, on a different machine, I pull that code down to my working area. Is there a command I can run to see the message (and then the version number I included) from the last commit I pulled down?

Comment: @fishpig If all you want to do is see is the commit message for HEAD you can use `git log HEAD --pretty=format:%s`

Answer (score 17):

You can use ***git rev-parse HEAD***

If you use maven to build your projects, consider using the maven SCM plugin, see:

http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html

Comment: One neat thing about this that I didn't expect originally is that it works even in a detached head state.  The reason is essentially that when you're in a detached head state, your working copy isn't pointing at a point in a branch, it's just pointing at a particular commit, which can be in many or no branches.  So the HEAD in that situation simply refers to that particular commit, not to the HEAD of whatever branch it might happen to belong to.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want git-describe.  That is the closes thing git has to a monotonic version number.